# Can someone verify this direct modulus proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its applications
[image]

To do this proof, I used this mod property
[image]

Here is my work [image]

What I did was basically expand both sides of (a-c) mod m and (b - d) mod m with that property. Then I saw that with what I was given, the two sides looked the same.
I am not sure if you're allowed to use that property to do this though.

Comment: The exercise is about *congruences* (mod as a relation), but the corollary and your work is about mod as an operator. Do you understand the difference between the two? To get started, [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879251/divisibility-for-7/879262#879262) for proofs of similar congruence rules.

Comment: is congruence just saying  a≡b(modm) or that m divides a - b?

Comment: Yes, by definition, $\,a\equiv b\pmod m\,$ is true iff $\ m\mid a-b\ \ $

Comment: @NotAsCommitedAndroider What does $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ mean verbally? It means, "$a$ is *congruent* to be $b$ modulo $m$." Notationally, we see that $a\equiv b\pmod{m} \Longleftrightarrow a-b=\ell\cdot m$ for some $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$; that is, just as Bill said, $m\mid (a-b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ we know that $b=a+sm$ for some integer $s$. Similarly, $d=c+tm$. Substracting, we have $b-d=(a-c)+(s-t)m$, which means that $a-c\equiv b-d\pmod{m}$. $\Box$